# Server-Client chat with fork and sockets

Tags: sockets, client, fork, chat, server

I want to create a chat room with a server that accepts any client and, when one client sends some text, the server sends that message to all other clients connected at that time. By now, my server is able to accept many clients (connected via sockets) and they can send messages displayed by the server. My server has a structure used to know at any time who (name and PID) is connected. My question is: How can I make so that my server redirects the message received from 1 client to all the others?

Server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef struct tabela
{
  char name[50];
  int PID;
} tab;

static tab *tabelaPersoane;

static int *nrPersoaneConectate;

void afisareConectati()
{
  int i;
  if (*nrPersoaneConectate > 0)
  {
    printf("Numarul de persoane conectate: %d", *nrPersoaneConectate);
    printf("\nPersoane conectate:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < *nrPersoaneConectate; i++)
    {
      printf("%s", tabelaPersoane[i].name);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  else
    printf("Niciun client conectat!\n");
}

void doprocessing(int sock, char *numeClient)
{
  //printf("doprocessing id=%d\n",sock);
  int n, i;
  char buffer[256], mesaj[256];
  while (1)
  {
    //printf("%d\n",nrPersoaneConectate);
    bzero(buffer, 256);

    n = read(sock, buffer, 255);
    if (strncmp(buffer, "exit", strlen("exit")) == 0)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < *nrPersoaneConectate; i++)
      {
        if (strcmp(numeClient, tabelaPersoane[i].name) == 0)
          if (i != *nrPersoaneConectate - 1)
          {
            tabelaPersoane[i] = tabelaPersoane[*nrPersoaneConectate - 1];
            //printf("%d\n",nrPersoaneConectate);
          }
      }
      (*nrPersoaneConectate)--;
      printf("S-a deconectat %s", numeClient);
      afisareConectati();
      break;
    }
    if (n < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (strcmp(buffer, "") != 0)
    {
      bzero(mesaj, 256);
      strncpy(mesaj, numeClient, strlen(numeClient) - 1);
      strcat(mesaj, ": ");
      strncat(mesaj, buffer, strlen(buffer));
      printf("%s", mesaj);
    }
    n = write(sock, "I got your message", 18);

    if (n < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR writing to socket");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  nrPersoaneConectate = mmap(NULL, sizeof *nrPersoaneConectate,
      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  tabelaPersoane = (tab *) mmap(0, sizeof(tab), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
      MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
  char buffer[256], mesaj[256];
  char buffer_pid[6];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n, i;
  *nrPersoaneConectate = 0;
  /* First call to socket() function */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (sockfd < 0)
  {
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Initialize socket structure */
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  portno = 51100;

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    perror("ERROR on binding");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Now start listening for the clients, here
   * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
   * for the incoming connection
   */

  if (listen(sockfd, 5) < 0)
  {
    printf("error ...");
    exit(1);
  }
  clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

  while (1)
  {
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    //printf("sockfd%d\n",sockfd);
    //printf("newsockfd%d\n",newsockfd);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR on accept");
      exit(1);
    }
    (*nrPersoaneConectate)++;
    /* Create child process */
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR on fork");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {

      /* This is the client process */
      close(sockfd);
      if (write(newsockfd, "Name: ", sizeof("Name: ")) < 0)
      {
        printf("Error on sending \"Name: \" string.");
        exit(1);
      }
      if (read(newsockfd, buffer, 255) < 0)
      {
        printf("Error on reading the name response.");
        exit(1);
      }
      strcpy(tabelaPersoane[(*nrPersoaneConectate) - 1].name, buffer);
      tabelaPersoane[(*nrPersoaneConectate) - 1].PID = getpid();
      bzero(mesaj, 256);
      strcpy(mesaj, "S-a conectat ");
      strncat(mesaj, buffer, strlen(buffer) - 1);
      strcat(mesaj, " PID: ");
      sprintf(buffer_pid, "%d", tabelaPersoane[(*nrPersoaneConectate) - 1].PID);
      strcat(mesaj, buffer_pid);
      strcat(mesaj, "\n");
      printf("%s", mesaj);
      afisareConectati();
      doprocessing(newsockfd, buffer);
      exit(0);
    }
    else
    {

      close(newsockfd);
      //printf("Close\n");         
    }
  } /* end of while */
}
```

Client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, portno, n;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct hostent *server;

  char buffer[256];

  if (argc < 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  portno = atoi(argv[2]);

  /* Create a socket point */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (sockfd < 0)
  {
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
  if (server == NULL )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *) server->h_addr,
  (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
  server->h_length);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  /* Now connect to the server */
  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    perror("ERROR connecting");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (read(sockfd, buffer, 255) < 0)
  {
    printf("Error on reading \"Name: \" string.");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("%s", buffer);
  bzero(buffer, 256);
  fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
  fflush(stdin);
  if (write(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0)
  {
    printf("Error on sending %s", buffer);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Now ask for a message from the user, this message
   * will be read by server
   */
  while (1)
  {
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
    //printf("buffer=%s\n",buffer);
    if (strncmp(buffer, "exit", strlen("exit")) == 0)
    {
      //printf("Am iesit din while!\n(Din client)");
      n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
      if (n < 0)
      {
        perror("ERROR writing to socket");
        exit(1);
      }
      break;
    }

    /* Send message to the server */
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR writing to socket");
      exit(1);
    }

    /* Now read server response */
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);

    if (n < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    //strcpy(buffer,"");
    //fflush(stdin);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1st you need to keep track of a conencted sockets.

Comment: How would I do that, considering the fact that in main I create a socket, passed it to the child and then I close it. So, I tried printing the socket id and it's the same for all my clients...How can I tell which is which?

Comment: Correction: "*a conencted*"="*all connected*"

Comment: I understood what you meant...but how can I do that...I told you, they all have the same id. I'm thinking of a shared array with all sockets id...

Comment: Even more, how can I make so that all my clients are always listening on a potential message from the server and on the same time waiting for the user to type something to send to the server?